# Has the option of search in discussions been removed from Google Search?

Tags: google-search

Has the option of search in discussions been removed from Google Search?

Where can I find it then?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly Google dropped the option to filter searches to "discussions" some time in late January (along with some others such as Blogs). Instead, [according to a Google spokesperson](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-filters-gone-17993.html):

> We’re always making changes to Search to help you find the most useful
>   things more easily. Now when you search, the type of results you can
>   select at the top of the page will vary depending on what makes sense
>   for your search.

<strike>You can still search discussion by going here directly: https://www.google.com/?tbm=dsc
or by adding `&tbm=dsc` to the end of a Google search url.</strike>

There is a long thread on the [Google Product](http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/websearch/Psb6OmlLJTg) list on this topic, there are various other solutions posted such as [user-scripts](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/293082) and a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/discussions-button-for-go/igjiggoeheaondbmhmilpmbdkpgcjmdn).

**Updated:** As of mid-July 2014 the discussion search filter has been removed entirely, so the above no longer works. People have come up with some [complicated alternatives](http://www.browsermedia.co.uk/2014/08/12/alternatives-discussion-search-filter/), but none as good as the original function.